# Complex Tabular Data Representation in Angular from an API

Tags: javascript, html, django, angular, frontend

I am trying to represent this table in angular13
[image]

I have created a backend API with Django Rest Framework with the following structure:

- FieldHead:{id,name} e.g Production
- FieldProperty: { id,   name,FieldHead} e.g PRODUCTION in HRS
- Product: {id,name,weight} e.g.20ltrs
- Supplier: {id, name} e.g. ABZ, XYZ
- ProductPropertyCost:{FieldProperty,Product,Supplier,cost}
  I am trying to find the best format I can return the data inorder to represent it in this format for every Supplier and how to represent it like this